# Does Oracle Instant Client 12c support LDAP?

Tags: oracle, ldap

I've been using Oracle Instant Client 12c as a lighter-weight alternative to the full Oracle installation. It works fine when I resolve service names with `tnsnames.ora`, but now I would like to configure it to use LDAP. I dropped our corporate `ldap.ora` and `sqlnet.ora` files into the `TNS_ADMIN` directory, but they aren't being used when I try to connect to a database. So I'm wondering, is LDAP even supported by the Oracle Instant Client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/ic-faq-094177.html#A8434

> **Can LDAP be used with Instant Client?**
>
> Yes, LDAP can be used with Instant Client, as of 10.1.0.4.